# How to add transition while moving items in a state or props rendered with a map

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, transition

Say I am rendering a list from a prop of a state using `.map` function.

I want to change the order of the list; so I change the order in my state or my prop. The change is reflected accordingly, but how am I to add a smooth transition in this case such that the user would feel like he/she has done something. Otherwise the user experience degrades.

He is a basic idea of what I want to achieve

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { key: 0, name: "Hello" },
        { key: 0, name: "Sello" }, // move this down with transition
        { key: 0, name: "Wello" }, // move this up with transition
        { key: 0, name: "Zello" },
        { key: 0, name: "Pello" },
        { key: 0, name: "Aello" }
      ]
    };
  }
  reShuffle = () => {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === 1) {
          return this.state.items[2];
        }
        if (index === 2) {
          return this.state.items[1];
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ transition: "all 0.5s ease" }}>
        <button onClick={this.reShuffle}> Click Me </button>
        {this.state.items.map(item => <li key={item.key}> {item.name} </li>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Easily replicable from here
https://codesandbox.io/s/648z61kvrn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing css transition on react element you need to deal with an additional state: the transition itself.

So first you change the state of your components so that css transition will alter them, then you change the state at the end of the transition to make react match the style of the component at the end of the transition.

In you case when you click to switch the element you have to compute a css alteration that will have the same effect as switching the elements, then when the transition ends, you actually switch the elements.

We will need to add a top property to the items, and a proper key:

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  items: [
    { key: 0, name: "Hello", top: 0 },
    { key: 1, name: "Sello", top: 0 }, // move this down
    { key: 2, name: "Wello", top: 0 }, // move this up
    { key: 3, name: "Zello", top: 0 },
    { key: 4, name: "Pello", top: 0 },
    { key: 5, name: "Aello", top: 0 }
  ],
  transitioning: {}
};
this.itemTransitionCount = 0;
```

}

Note the itemTransitionCount for later.

First wrap your `<li>` elements in an `<ul>` element and attach a ref to the `<ul>`:

```
ulLoad = c => (this.ulDom = c);
render() {
    ...
    <ul
        ref={this.ulLoad}
        style={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-block" }}
    >
        {
            this.state.items.map(item => (
                <li
                    key={item.key}
                    onTransitionEnd={this.itemTransitionEnd}
                    style={{
                        transition: item.top ? "top 0.5s ease" : "none",
                        position: "relative",
                        top: item.top
                    }}
                >
                    {item.name}
                </li>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
    ....
}
```

This will allow to compute the relative position of the children `<li>`s

Then change your reShuffle handler this way:

```
reShuffle = () => {
this.setState({
  items: this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
    if (index === 1) {
      const top2 = this.ulDom.children[2].offsetTop;
      const top1 = this.ulDom.children[1].offsetTop;
      const top = top2 - top1;
      return { ...this.state.items[1], top };
    }
    if (index === 2) {
      const top1 = this.ulDom.children[1].offsetTop;
      const top2 = this.ulDom.children[2].offsetTop;
      const top = top1 - top2;
      return { ...this.state.items[2], top };
    }
    return item;
  })
});
```

This code will initiate the top transition that we want to set on the li items => the switching animation will occur during the next render.

The we catch the end of both animation with the onTransitionEnd handler (the check on evt.target !== evt.currentTarget is there because transition event bubbles, the count is there because both elements will raise the event but we want to act once at the end of both transitions):

```
itemTransitionEnd = evt => {
if (evt.target !== evt.currentTarget) return;
// alert("transitionEnd");
this.itemTransitionCount++;
if (this.itemTransitionCount < 2) return;
this.itemTransitionCount = 0;
this.setState({
  items: this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
    if (index === 1) {
      return { ...this.state.items[2], top: 0 };
    }
    if (index === 2) {
      return { ...this.state.items[1], top: 0 };
    }
    return item;
  })
});
```

};

The code above actually swithes the element at the end of the transition and reset their relative top (the transition count is also reset for next transition).

This illustrates a two step rendering for a css transition animation in React.

[Working sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7ky7370xl0)

Comment: Brilliant! the transition start and end thing is just to good! You should put this as a medium post or something. I racked my brains for this.